# Manual bevelling works, but not the one limited by a Vertex Group

Tags: workflow, bevel

I try to bevel all the edges visible on the following picture. I select an edge and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and then choose *Assign to Active Group* (which is named `2mmBevel`). As can be seen on the picture I limit Bevel to this Vertex Group.

[image]

The problem is that it doesn't work. It did work that way for those edges that can be seen bevelled. Sometimes it worked for single edges. Sometimes I had to select several edges and assign them to Active Group together, they refused to get bevelled separately.

Anyway for this particular selected edge - once I add it to the Active Group - all other bevels disappear, like this:

[image]

The strange thing is, that when I try to bevel this edge manually it works:

[image]

What is the problem here? How can I bevel the remaining edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it work. May be you not assign the vertices correctly.
[image]

You should choose "Assign to New Group" from the Panel.

[image]

You can press "select" to make sure that you assign the vertices correctly.

[image]

You can assign this three vertices to bevel the remaining edges.
[image]

Disabling "Clamp Overlap" also can fix the problem for the questioner

Comment: I first define a new group (in my case it is named 2mmBevel), set it as Active Group and then go over my model, decide which edges I want to add to it, select that edge and then I click "Assign to Active Group". If I will click "Assign to New Group" - I will create a new group on each edge that I want to add...

Comment: If still unsuccess, try select the Group and press "Assign" button from property panel in third image. Remember the Vertex Groups are only store the vertices data and weight, not the edge or face.

Comment: This also didn't help. Is there some sort of a log file where I can see error messages etc..?

Comment: you can upload your .blend file

Comment: Try to check Clamp Overlap setting

Comment: Disabling "Clamp Overlap" solved the problem. Please mention this in the answer so I can mark it as the correct solution.